# Reading ArrayList as object from file?

Tags: java, io

Alright, so I have done the following:

1. I've added objects to an ArrayList and written the whole list as an object to a file.
2. The problem is when trying to read them back as a whole. I get the following error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at persoana.Persoana.main(Student.java:64)**

Here's my code: (Everything is in a try catch so nothing to worry about that)

**Writing**

```
Student st1 = new Student("gigi","prenume","baiat","cti");
        Student st2= new Student("borcan","numegfhfh","baiat cu ceva","22c21");

        List <Student> studenti = new ArrayList<Student>();
        studenti = Arrays.asList(st1,st2);

FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream("t.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(studenti);
            oos.close();
```

**Reading**

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.ser");
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

             ArrayList <Student> ds;

             ds = (ArrayList <Student>)ois.readObject(); 

             ois.close();
```

The problem occurs at this line:

```
ds = (ArrayList <Student>)ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Try (Student)ois.readObject();

Comment: A note, here: List <Student> studenti = new ArrayList<Student>(); studenti = Arrays.asList(st1,st2); you are wasting an ArrayList

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` doesn't return an ArrayList. Check its javadoc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that you are creating the `List` of `Student` through `Arrays.asList`. This method doesn't return an `ArrayList` but an `Arrays.ArrayList` which is a different class, meant to backen an Array and to be able to use it as a `List`. Both `ArrayList` and `Arrays.ArrayList` implement `List` interface but they are not the same class.

You should cast it to appropriate object:

```
List<Student> ds = (List<Student>)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the following lines:

```
ArrayList <Student> ds;
ds = (ArrayList<Student>)ois.readObject();
```

to

```
List<Student> ds = (List<Student>)ois.readObject();
```

Comment: No problem. See Jack's answer for an explanation of why your original code didn't work.